# No me aparece el boton para ejecutar el codigo que deberia estar al lado izquierdo de "split editor right"

Tags: vscode

No me aparece el boton para ejecutar el codigo que deberia estar al lado izquierdo de "split editor right" y al ejecutar desde "terminal>run active file" que supongo debe ser lo mismo que ejcutar, en la terminal se ejecuta como si no estuviera escribiendo codigo valido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te falta alguna extension.. uno no ejecuta un archivo js asi como asi...